# Identifying what is returned when submitting a form using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to identify what a page returns when using jquery? I'm submitting a form here using jquery like this:

```
$("#sform").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        url: "user_verify.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#form_msg").html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

​

The user_verify.php page does its usual verification work, and returns error messages or on success adds a user to the db. If its errors its a bunch of error messages or on success its usually "You have successfully signed up". Can I somehow identify using jquery if its errors messages its returning or the success message. So that way if its errors I can use that data in the form, or if its success, I could close the form and display a success message.

Comment: I noticed that there is a problem in your code. Look at this line :
             
    data: $(this).serialize(),
Inside $.ajax jquery method, "this" is bind to the global window object and not $('#sform')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#form_msg").html(data);
}
```

You can manipulate `data` in any way you want. You can return a JSON (use `dataType`) encoded string from server side and process data in the `success` function

```
success: function(data) {
    if(data->success == 'ok'){
       // hide the form, show another hidden div.
    }
}
```

so `user_verify.php` should print for example:

```
// .... queries 
$dataReturn = array();
$dataReturn['success'] = 'ok';
$dataReturn['additional'] = 'test';
echo json_encode($dataReturn);
die; // to prevent any other prints.
```

Comment: Yes, you return as JSON, let me modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make you php return 0 if error so you do something like this inside

```
 success: function(data) {
       if(data==0){
       //do error procedure
       }else{
        //do success procedure
       }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do and something like this:

```
$.ajax({
type:"POST", //php method
url:'process.php',//where to send data...
cache:'false',//IE FIX
data: data, //what will data contain 
//check is data sent successfuly to process.php
//success:function(response){
//alert(response)
//} 
success: function(){ //on success do something...
$('.success').delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);  
//alert('THX for your mail!');
} //end sucess 
}).error(function(){ //if sucess FAILS!! put .error After $.ajax. EXAMPLE :$.ajax({}).error(function(){}; 
alert('An error occured!!');
$('.thx').hide();
});
 //return false prevent Redirection
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can checke the "data" parameter in "success" callback function.
I noticed that there is a problem in your code. Look at this line :

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

Inside $.ajax jquery method, "this" is bind to the global window object and not $('#sform')